# Enter an exited docker container in interactive mode

Tags: docker

I have an exited docker container `Exited (1) 8 seconds ago`.
And I would like to enter it in interactive mode (in bash mode) to check what went wrong how do I do that?

I know I can start an image (`docker run -it IMAGE_NAME /bin/bash`) to enter the interactive mode directly.

How do I re-run an exited container and enter the interactive mode? `docker start -a CONTAINERID` will cause it to exit 1 again. Because there is a automated command to start by default which specified in `Dockerfile` as `CMD java ...`

Answer (score 2):

You can turn the current state of a container into an image using `docker commit` command.

For example, if that were the way you ran the original image

```
$ docker run ubuntu touch what_went_wrong_file
```

you could use `docker ps` to see the name of the container

```
$ docker ps -a -n 1 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
abcdef012345        ubuntu              "touch what_went_wro…"   42 seconds ago      Exited (0) 23 seconds ago                       ron_pringadi
```

and then commit its changes

```
$ docker commit abcdef012345 what_went_wrong_image # or
$ docker commit ron_pringadi what_went_wrong_image
```

Now that you have an image you can run it in a new container and explore its content

```
$ docker run -it what_went_wrong_image bash
root@01234abcdef:/# ls -l what_went_wrong_file
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Feb 31 24:00 what_went_wrong_file
```